# User control TextBlock.FontSize cannot be changed when style defined in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control that doesn't have xaml part, it's completely written in C#, but the Control template is written in xaml using ResourceDictionary, this is mainly due the issue related to naming user controls (http://devdump.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/cannot-set-name-attribute-value-error/), so, Control Template is loaded dynamically in control's constructor.

This control is similar to TabControl, it has items and each item have Header and Content, thus the control template is used (to filter out the content and display only the header). It all works fine except that when I now add the style (FontSize) in App.xaml for TextBlock I cannot change the FontSize locally, I cannot change even the FontSize in the template it self, it is always using the one defined in app.xaml. If I remove the style from app.xaml, everything works fine.

My global style looks like (app.xaml):

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
</Style>
```

My template is something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="MyControl">

    <StackPanel x:Name="mainStack" Background="Transparent">
        <StackPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding HeaderForeground}">
            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Source}" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger SourceName="mainStack" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=HoverBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The code which I use to load the template from resource dictionary is:

```
ResourceDictionary dic = new ResourceDictionary();
dic.Source = new Uri("mynamespace", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
this.Template = (ControlTemplate)dic["MyTemplate"];
```

So, to summarize, changing the TextBlock.FontSize is not possible, global value is always used, it cannot be overridden even if setting it directly in template itself.

Here is an update on this issue:

If I have a UserControl which has TextBlock defined, and if I want to change it's properties via attached properties it won't have effect, global style will be still applied and any local settings will be ignored.

User control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>Inside the user cotnrol TextBlock</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Main window:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Naked TextBlock"/>
    <local:MyControl TextBlock.FontSize="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And same global style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>           
</Style>
```

Comment: I can't see anywhere you tried to set `TextBlock.FontSize` other than the global one in App.xaml

Comment: OK, you are right, I didn't supplied the example but as I said, if you try to change the TextBlock.FontSize to something other than defined in app.xaml, it won't have any effect. Even if I change the control template and use TextBlock directly, it still won't be changed, like <TextBlock FontSize=22><ContentPresenter...></TextBlock>

Comment: You've somehow caused this problem yourself. Changing the `FontSize` for any normal .NET control works just fine, so you clearly have a problem with your control. However, you didn't provide us with a [clear, concise working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Describing it is not enough. Follow the advice in the link and edit your question with some code that we can copy and paste into a new project to determine what your problem is.

Comment: Sorry for that, the thing is that my code is not so trivial and it would need an effort to set it up. But with further testing I isolated the problem and I will post an update.